# What is the Ehcache TTL for Grails?

Tags: grails, ehcache

Is TTL for ehcache in Grails defaulted to 0? I'm trying to locate documentation on the subject and I'm unsuccessful.

I'm simply guessing based on Ehcache documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default cache TTL is 2 minutes. All caches use defaults defined in `ehcache-failsafe.xml` that's bundled with the jar (in the root dir) unless they're explicitly configured, or if you create your own `ehcache.xml` and put it in the runtime classpath to prevent the failsafe file from being used.

See http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xml for an example file that's heavily commented.